# UITextView how edit some strings programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am using this code in UITextView

```
nsstring *var = @"2013 11 30 this is an example";

    NSRange isRange30Nov = [fechaHorarios rangeOfString:@"20131130" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if(isRange30Nov.location == 0) {
        // FOUND
    }
```

**And need change to bold only the date in my UITextView how can i do?**
thanks!!

Comment: You might want to take a look at NSAttributedString

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using attributed strings:

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:var];

    [attrString beginEditing];
    [attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                       value:myFontBold
                       range:isRange30Nov];

    [attrString endEditing];
```